# AWS::Lambda::Function, JS file as source

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to deploy lambda functions through cloudformation.  My project is setup

```
-src
--lambdas
---lambda1.js
---lambda2.js
---lambda3.js
```

Then I'm trying to upload each lambda file as a lambda function

```
Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: lambda1
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaAtEdgeRole.Arn
      Runtime: nodejs10.x
      Handler: index.handler
```

Now I'm trying to get the code, but I don't see anywhere where I can upload a JS file.  I can see ZIP, but then I would have to add a build step for each file to zip it up.  Where can I say `lambda_src = ./src/lambdas/lambda1.js`

Comment: Tools like SAM and serverless framework can help here, though you can certainly do it manually if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is **working example** trying to reproduce your setup for `aws cloudformation package` execution.

**directory structure**:

```
.
├── src
│   └── lambdas
│       ├── lambda1.js
│       ├── lambda2.js
│       └── lambda3.js
└── template.yaml
```

**template.yaml**

```
Resources:

  MyFunction1:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: lambda1
      Runtime: nodejs10.x
      Handler: index.handler
      Code: ./src/lambdas/lambda1.js  
  
  MyFunction2:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: lambda1
      Runtime: nodejs10.x
      Handler: index.handler
      Code: ./src/lambdas/lambda2.js  


  MyFunction3:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: lambda1
      Runtime: nodejs10.x
      Handler: index.handler
      Code: ./src/lambdas/lambda3.js
```

**execute in root folder of the project**

```
aws cloudformation package  --template-file template.yaml --output-template-file output.yml --s3-bucket <your-bucket-name>
```

Then you can deploy your `output.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aws cli [cloudformation package](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html) for packaging your lambda code with cloudformation. But you need an S3 bucket beforehand for doing that.

```
    $ aws cloudformation package \
            --template-file template.yml \
            --output-template-file packaged-template.yml \
            --s3-bucket {s3bucket}

    $ aws cloudformation deploy \
            --template-file packaged-template.yml \
            --stack-name {s3bucket}
```

Following is the directory structure

```
    $ tree
    ├── template.yml
    ├── lambda_one.py
    └── lambda_two/
        ├── index.py
        └── some_module.py
```

and your cloudoformation definition should provide the directory path

```
   LambdaTwo:
        Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
        Properties:
          Handler: index.lambda_handler
          Code: lambda_two/   #lambda code directory
          Runtime: …
   LambdaOne:
        Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
        Properties:
          Handler: index.lambda_handler
          Code: lambda_one.py    #just one file
          Runtime: …
```

Post packaing the your tempalte will look like below :

```
    LambdaOne:
        Properties:
          Code:
              S3Bucket: cf-templates-abcdefghjklm-ap-southeast-2
              S3Key: 35f69109a3a3f87e999f028f034

     ..
   LambdaTwo:
     Properties:
       Code:
         S3Bucket: cf-templates-abcdefghjklm-ap-southeast-2
         S3Key: cca5b023ed6603eabf9421471b65d68b
```

For the simplicity, you can wrap this whole thing into a Makefile

And last but not the least if you dont wanna do all the plumbing, you can use AWS SAM. You can check this one [Tutorial: Deploying a Hello World application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started-hello-world.html)
 to appreciate it.

Comment: I tried setting the code as you have it defined in LambdaOne(`Code: lambdas/lambda1.js`) but it gives me the following error: `Value of property Code must be an object`

Comment: The code is not indented propertly you can refer this [AWS::Lambda::Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html), I updated the indentation, you can use [cfn-linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint).

Comment: I don't see the difference... I don't know if it's cached or what.

Comment: no there is no cahcing, after updating the syntax in the original template you again need to package the template and use the packaged template for deployment.

Comment: No, you said there was an indentation error in your code, I don't see the difference

Comment: yes there is I earlier <Code> was aligned with <Properties> which was failing for you.
You can follow along this [workshop](https://cfn101.workshop.aws/40-workshop-part-02/30-package-and-deploy/100-lab-12-package-deploy.html) this will help and give good explanation as well.